# JavaScript same functions, different implementation decided on runtme

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to change JavaScript implementations at run time?

I have a web application which connects to the server by [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).
If there is any problem connecting to the server using SignalR at runtime, I want to change the services functions implementations to work with regular XHR.

I have one js file with the following functions to connect via **SignalR**:

```
function initializeConnection() {
    // Initialize connection using SignalR
}

function sendEcho() {
    // Sending echo message using signalR
}
```

And another js file with the same functions for connection via **XHR**:

```
function initializeConnection() {
    // Initialize connection using XHR
}

function sendEcho() {
    // Sending echo message using XHR
}
```

I know it is impossible to have them loaded at the same time.
I know I can use one file with a toggle within each function.

I thought maybe I can switch between these files by loading & unloading them at runtime. Is this possible? If so, is this the best way for such an issue?

What is the best way for supplying different implementations at runtime?

Comment: `var func = {success:{//OTHER FUNCTIONS},fail:{//OTHER FUNCTIONS}}` IF successful, use `func.success` else `func.fail`..

Comment: Yes, one could use namespaces.

Comment: You can include both at runtime and easily define which one to use, but how do you determine that choice?  I can give you a simple example but without the logic to decide which to use there's no way you can do what you're asking.

Comment: @Rayon 's answer is a good way for determining which implementation to use for connecting to the Server. I start with SignarR by default, if it fails during the initialization or at the sending an echo message, then I should switch to use XHR for all the functions that connect to the server.

Comment: [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to define both implementations as objects with same signatures and just set the namespace to a variable:

```
;var MyStuff = {
    //SignalR
    SignalR: {
        initializeConnection: function(){console.log('SignalR.initializeConnection()')},
        sendEcho: function(){console.log('SignalR.sendEcho()')}
    },

    //XHR
    XHR: {
        initializeConnection: function(){console.log('XHR.initializeConnection()')},
        sendEcho: function(){console.log('XHR.sendEcho()')}
    }
};

//Do whatever check you want to
var mNamespace = (1 === 2) ? MyStuff.SignalR : MyStuff.XHR;

//Call the instance
mNamespace.initializeConnection();
```

You can also keep them split in two files and add them both to MyStuff dynamicallly:

```
//File 1
;var MyStuff = (MyStuff === undefined) ? {} : MyStuff;
MyStuff.SignalR = {..};

//File 2
;var MyStuff = (MyStuff === undefined) ? {} : MyStuff;
MyStuff.XHR = {..};
```

Answer (score 1):

One pattern that can help you is the "lazy function definition" or "self-defining function" pattern. It consists of (as its name points out) the redefinition of a function at runtime. It's useful when your function has to do some initial preparatory work and it needs to do it only once.

In your case, this "preparatory" work would be selecting the function that handles the client-server connection.

For instance:

```js
var sendMessage = function() {
  // Perform a check, or try a first message using your default connection flavour
  // Depending on the result, redefine the function accordingly
  sendMessage = sendMessageUsingWhatever;
};

//Use sendMessage anywhere you want, it'll use the proper protocol
```

This pattern was particularly handy when dealing with browsers and their peculiarities:

```js
var addHandler = document.body.addEventListener ?
  function(target, eventType, handler) {
    target.addEventListener(eventType, handler, false);
  } :
  function(target, eventType, handler) {
    target.attachEvent("on" + eventType, handler);
  };
```

In this case, it is useful to determine which which way to attach event listeners depending on the availability (or not) of a particular method.

It has its drawbacks though. For instance, any properties you've previously added to the original function will be lost when it redefines itself.

Hope it helps or at least gives you some ideas.